# I need to form a loop to read in answers to survey questions and store them in a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

My assignment is asking for:

- 2 dimensional array to hold the respondents' results
- displaySurveyResults() method with an int parameter
- String array to hold 10 questions
- enterQuestions() method
- logResponse() method with 3 parameters

So far I have created a one dimensional array to hold questions and a lopp to read them in. I can not figured out how to use those questions in order to store results into a two dimensional array.
My code so far

```
public class Survey {

private String surveyTitle;

public String getSurveyTitle(){
    return surveyTitle;
}
static int respondantID=0;
static int generateRespondantID(){
    return ++respondantID;
}
public Survey(String surveyTitle){
    this.surveyTitle = surveyTitle;
}
public Survey(){
    surveyTitle = "Customer Survey";
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Survey s = new Survey();
    System.out.println(s.getSurveyTitle());
    System.out.println(Survey.generateRespondantID());
    System.out.println();

    //Array to Hold Questions
String[] questions = new String[10]; // declare array
    questions[0] = "Question 1";
    questions[1] = "Question 2";
    questions[2] = "Question 3";
    questions[3] = "Question 4";
    questions[4] = "Question 5";
    questions[5] = "Question 6";
    questions[6] = "Question 7";
    questions[7] = "Question 8";
    questions[8] = "Question 9";
    questions[9] = "Question 10";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

    //loop to read in questions
    for(int index=0; index<10; index++){
    System.out.println("Please enter a question");
    questions[index] = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Question: " + questions[index]);
    }

    //Array to hold results of questions
    int[][] answers = new int[10][10];

    //loop to read in answers to questions
    for(int index=0; index<10; index++){
    System.out.println([index]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a two dimensional String array to store this data

column 1 would store the questions and the other columns would store the response from people

if you have 5 questions and 3 people to answer the questions, then you will have 
String[5][3]

You can run the program below to store the data

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sizeOfQuestions = 0;
    int sizeOfRespondants = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the total number of questions");
    sizeOfQuestions = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the total number of respondants");
    sizeOfRespondants = sc.nextInt();

    String[][] surveyPool = new String[sizeOfQuestions][sizeOfRespondants];


    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfQuestions; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter question " + (i + 1));
        surveyPool[i][0] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter the answers : \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfQuestions; i++){
        System.out.println("Question" + surveyPool[i][0]);
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfRespondants; j++){
            System.out.println("Answer by " + (j + 1));
            surveyPool[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
        String[] questions = new String[10]; // declare array
        questions[0] = "Question 1";
        questions[1] = "Question 2";
        questions[2] = "Question 3";
        questions[3] = "Question 4";
        questions[4] = "Question 5";
        questions[5] = "Question 6";
        questions[6] = "Question 7";
        questions[7] = "Question 8";
        questions[8] = "Question 9";
        questions[9] = "Question 10";
```

Here is one way to do the responses

```
        int n = 6; // number of responders (0 thru 5)
        String[][] responses = new String[n][10];

        // First dimension is responder # 
        responses[0][0] = "2"; // responder 0 answers 2 for question # 0
        responses[0][1] = "3"; // responder 0 answers 3 for question # 1
        responses[0][2] = "1"; // responder 0 answers 1 for question # 2
        // and so on
        responses[1][0] = "1"; // responder 1 answers 1 for question # 0
        responses[1][1] = "4"; // responder 1 answers 4 for question # 1
        responses[1][2] = "2"; // responder 1 answers 2 for question # 2
        // and so on
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       for ( responder = 0; reponder < n; responder++) {
            for (int questionNo = 0; questionNo < 10; questionNo++) {

               // Ask question
               System.out.println(questions[questionNo]);

               String answer = input.nextLine(); // one answer per line.
               // get answer from somewhere, maybe console
               responses[responder][questionNo] = answer;
            }
       }
```

Comment: there is supposed to be 10 responders answering the same survey questions
and the questions are supposed to prompt an integer answer.